# how to change combobox background without PresentationFramework.Aero2

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

how do i change the background of my combobox without to use `PresentationFramework.Aero2` since you getting error with that on win 7 and under

and you are getting `PresentationFramework.Aero2`
with this code

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Border}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="Red" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Border x:Name="splitBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                            <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="F1 M 0,0 L 2.667,2.66665 L 5.3334,0 L 5.3334,-1.78168 L 2.6667,0.88501 L0,-1.78168 L0,0 Z" Fill="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Glyph}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>`
```

Comment: Did you try to let Visual Studio create a copy of the control template for you? Because I think the custom style you provided with your question lacks important parts of the Control Template (like e.g. Triggers). Just right-click on a combo box in the document outline window and choose edit template -> edit a copy...

Comment: yes thats add the PresentationFramework.Aero2 wich are giving me a xamlparse exception wich are relating to missing PresentationFramework.Aero2 on win 7 and under

Answer (score 0):

I can't completely understand why you receive an error when creating a copy of the template, but the default WPF style for the ComboBox and ComboBoxItem can also be found on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=vs.100).aspx

Maybe you can use this one to manipulate the template in the way you need it to be.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this 
put this in your combobox

```
Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxTest2}"
```

and this  in your ressource

```
 <Style x:Key="ComboBoxTest2" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ToggleButton Grid.Column="2" Focusable="false" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" >
                            <ToggleButton.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Border x:Name="Border"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CornerRadius="5" Background="#FF303030" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" />
                                        <Border Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="5,0,0,5"  Margin="1"  Background="Black"  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" />
                                        <Path x:Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="1"  Fill="#FFEAEAEA" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </ToggleButton.Template>
                        </ToggleButton>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" IsHitTestVisible="False"  Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Margin="3"  />
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Visibility="Hidden" IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                        <Popup x:Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True"  Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Slide">
                            <Grid  x:Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Background="#FF303030" />
                                <ScrollViewer SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```